# Formula on Salesforce report

Tags: reporting, analytics

I would like to create a formula field on my report using some fields of my report. The formula would like to create is: ((= 90%) + (=100%) * 0,2)/(< 90%)

This formula must be at the end of all rows. Anyboy knows how to do it?

[image: I need this formula on this report]

Comment: Can you describe your requirement somewhat more? What value needs to come out of the formula on which fields?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Fred !
Well, Our salesman are owner of theis own opportunities. And these opportunities has its stages and its probabiliy to close (10%, 30%, 50% 70% 90%, related to the opportunity stage).
Each salesman has their quote to achieve and this quote is saved in a custom User field.
With those information, our company "created" a formula to show the probability of each salesman achive the quote.

Comment: Legend: 
A = all opportunities of salesman less then 90% | 
B = all opportunities of salesman closed win (100%) |
C = all opportunities of salesman with 90% |
X = the salesman quote (custom field on User object) |

The formula that I need to show per Salesman: 

(A * 0.20) / (X - B - C)

Comment: Where i wrote "quote", should be "quota"... Sorry... My english isn't good...

Answer (score 0):

First of all: My advise is to start using Quotas rather than using a custom field on the user object. It gives you a more solid way of tracking Sales performance. If you want to use custom fields for Quotas, I would advise to create a custom object for this, rather than use the User object. This to prevent all sorts of problems. For starters: The user doesn’t necessarily have to be the Opportunity owner.

Having said this, the answer to your question is:

1. You have to create a Report Type on Users with Opportunities (Setup > Build > Create > Report types
2. After you created the report type, you create a report with this report type
3. Make it a summary report, and group on Users
4. Add a formula to the report like the screenshot below.

Just to give you an example:

[image]

With this you will be able to report on Opportunity vs Target per user. Just create other formulas to meet your needs.
Again: it makes a lot more sense to forcast and report on Opportunity owners rather than Users.

Comment: thanks for your reply again! But my problem is I need to use on my final formula the result of other formulas and other summary fields. Example: I need to group all opportunities with probability 100% and use it in my formula. Understand? And this, I don't know how to do...

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. The fields you put formulas on have to be Summarized (grouped) fields.